# how do you get a crimson biome in a corruption world?

Tags: terraria

so, I have a corruption world and I want to beat the BOC in terreria.  which means I have to get something that can spread crimsion.  can u guys help me out?

Comment: Keep in mind the same character can use different worlds

Comment: Just wanted to note that in Terraria 1.4 (released May 2020), you can buy the other evil biome seeds from the Dryad in a hardmode graveyard biome, eliminating the need for creating a different world. [Wiki link](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Dryad#Tips)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no issue with going between worlds, you could technically bring crimson seeds (dropped by Eye of Cthulhu in Crimson worlds) to your Corruption world, and if your Corruption world is in Hardmode then you could also bring some Crimson blocks from the other world and place them in your Corruption world, as at that point the Crimson blocks could spread to regular stone, wood, sand, etc. in the world.

Alternatively, the "Drunk world" seed; 5162020 can generate both a Crimson and a Corruption biome in the same world.